# Get notified of all new private channels in twilio programmable chat

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am designing a chat app where a user can create a private channel with a topic and all other logged in users will be notified about new private channels that get created. Users can then check the topic and if the topic is interesting, they can join the channel. The channels have to be private and cannot be public.

To achieve above goal, I assign "service admin" role to my users when creating tokens for them. And then on the client side (js SDK), I listen to the event "channelAdded" on the Twilio.Chat.Client instance.

The issue is, the event does not fire when new private channels are created. Does it mean that the even the service role I have assigned to my user is incorrect or the channelAdded method is not suppose to fire for new private channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case "all users" should be seeing the private channels, this matches the definition of a Chat **public channel**, which you can use today.

Since **all users** will need to be able to find the channel in order to read the topic and decide to join the channel, these channels should be public.

Chat private channels are private by definition - only people **invited** to a private channel can see it.

Please note that "public" and "private" are only terms within your Chat Service Instance; public channels are not visible outside your service to third parties.

Comment: Actually, I have two set of users - visitors and agents - on my chat application. I want that all my agents should be able to see the channel and not my visitors. Therefore, when a visitor requests to chat, I create a private channel. And since all my agents have service admin role, I expect them to be able to get notified when a new private is available. That is why I was using Private and not public channels.

Comment: I even tried with using public channel instead of private and still the onChannelAdded does not fire.

Open http://livechatpoc.azurewebsites.net/chat/agent and see code init() method in agent-chat-console.js

Then open http://livechatpoc.azurewebsites.net/chat/visitor and see initiateChat() method in visitor-chat-console.js.

Both of these pages use a common c# code to create a token. The default service role is “Service Admin” and channel role is “Channel Admin”.

Hit submit on second page to debug.

Comment: As per https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.11.1/docs/Client.html#event:channelAdded, the channel added will be fired for private channels only. So public channels will not work for me.

Comment: So your option would be to invite agents to the newly created private chat, as far as i know the service admin will not see/be notified about a new private chat either.

Comment: another option would be to create a private chat into which all agents are subscribed and post a new user request event there - then parse it on client side and show agent prompt to join that private chat if they want to. i'd do it this way.

Comment: If I use public channels instead, is there a way that all users get notified whenever a new public channel is created?

Comment: no, but you could use the suggested always-subscribed private channel in combination with webhooks to emulate that

Comment: Thanks, @Berkus! I am using the always-subscribed private channel

Comment: Hi @Berkus.. I am using your approach of always-subscribed private channels, but need some help here. Since twilio has a channel limit per user of 1000, so I have a scheduled job that removes members from channel periodically and should be added back if a new message is added in the channel. I want the user to not know that they have been unsubscribed but simply add them back in wehbook on OnMessageAdded event. Now I want the new channel to load and show new message notifications without reloading the page (using js events) , is there a way to do it?